# Missing return in a function expected to return 'UITableViewCell'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**EDIT 1: Revised code - still does not work.**

I've got two custom cells.

The first cell (and only the first cell) will be of type **CurrentIssueFrontCoverTableViewCell**, and the rest of the cells will be of type **CurrentIssueArticlesTableViewCell**. I am getting the error, described in the title, when declaring my cellForRowAtIndexPath function. Any idea of to fix this ? Why is it not detecting that I'm returning the cell in my "if" loop ?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell {

    let row = indexPath.row

    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        let cellWithCoverImage = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CurrentIssueFrontCoverTableCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CurrentIssueFrontCoverTableViewCell

        if let currentIssueFrontCoverObject = currentIssueObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? IssueElement {

            let title = currentIssueFrontCoverObject.title ?? ""

            let timeStampDateObject = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: NSTimeInterval(currentIssueFrontCoverObject.timeStamp))
            let timeStampDateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(timeStampDateObject)

            let issueNumber = currentIssueFrontCoverObject.issueNumber ?? ""
            let volumeNumber = currentIssueFrontCoverObject.volumeNumber ?? ""

            let nodeID = currentIssueFrontCoverObject.nodeID ?? 0

            let imageURL = currentIssueFrontCoverObject.imageURL ?? ""


            cellWithCoverImage.request?.cancel()

            if let coverImage = self.imageCache.objectForKey(imageURL) as? UIImage {
                cellWithCoverImage.currentIssueFrontCoverImageView.image = coverImage
            } else {
                cellWithCoverImage.currentIssueFrontCoverImageView.image = nil
                cellWithCoverImage.request = Alamofire.request(.GET, imageURL).responseImage() { response in
                    if let coverImage = response.result.value {
                        self.imageCache.setObject(response.result.value!, forKey: imageURL)
                        cellWithCoverImage.currentIssueFrontCoverImageView.image = coverImage

                    } else {

                    }
                }
            }
        } else {

        }

        return cellWithCoverImage

        // Populating data in the "Articles" type cells

} else if indexPath.row >= 1 {

        let cellWithoutCoverImage = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CurrentIssueArticlesTableCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CurrentIssueArticlesTableViewCell

        if let currentIssueArticleObject = currentIssueObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? IssueElement {

            let title = currentIssueArticleObject.title ?? ""

            let timeStampDateObject = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: NSTimeInterval(currentIssueArticleObject.timeStamp))
            let timeStampDateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(timeStampDateObject)

            let author = currentIssueArticleObject.author ?? ""

            let issueNumber = currentIssueArticleObject.issueNumber ?? ""
            let volumeNumber = currentIssueArticleObject.volumeNumber ?? ""

            let articleContent = currentIssueArticleObject.articleContent ?? ""

            let nodeID = currentIssueArticleObject.nodeID ?? 0


            cellWithoutCoverImage.currentIssueArticlesHeadlineLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleHeadline)
            cellWithoutCoverImage.currentIssueArticlesHeadlineLabel.text = title

            cellWithoutCoverImage.currentIssueArticlesAuthorLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleSubheadline)
            cellWithoutCoverImage.currentIssueArticlesAuthorLabel.text = author

            cellWithoutCoverImage.currentIssueArticlesPublishDateLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleSubheadline)
            cellWithoutCoverImage.currentIssueArticlesPublishDateLabel.text = timeStampDateString

            return cellWithoutCoverImage

        } else {

        }
    }

    else {

    }
}
```

**EDIT 1: Revised code - still does not work**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell {

    let row = indexPath.row

    switch(row) {


    case 0:

        let cellWithCoverImage = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CurrentIssueFrontCoverTableCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CurrentIssueFrontCoverTableViewCell

        if let currentIssueFrontCoverObject = currentIssueObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? IssueElement {

            let title = currentIssueFrontCoverObject.title ?? ""

            let timeStampDateObject = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: NSTimeInterval(currentIssueFrontCoverObject.timeStamp))
            let timeStampDateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(timeStampDateObject)

            let issueNumber = currentIssueFrontCoverObject.issueNumber ?? ""
            let volumeNumber = currentIssueFrontCoverObject.volumeNumber ?? ""

            let nodeID = currentIssueFrontCoverObject.nodeID ?? 0

            let imageURL = currentIssueFrontCoverObject.imageURL ?? ""


            cellWithCoverImage.request?.cancel()

            if let coverImage = self.imageCache.objectForKey(imageURL) as? UIImage {
                cellWithCoverImage.currentIssueFrontCoverImageView.image = coverImage
            } else {
                cellWithCoverImage.currentIssueFrontCoverImageView.image = nil
                cellWithCoverImage.request = Alamofire.request(.GET, imageURL).responseImage() { response in
                    if let coverImage = response.result.value {
                        self.imageCache.setObject(response.result.value!, forKey: imageURL)
                        cellWithCoverImage.currentIssueFrontCoverImageView.image = coverImage

                    } else {

                        return

                    }
                }
            }
        } else {

            break
        }

        return cellWithCoverImage;

        // Populating data in the "Articles" type cells



    default:

        let cellWithoutCoverImage = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CurrentIssueArticlesTableCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CurrentIssueArticlesTableViewCell

        if let currentIssueArticleObject = currentIssueObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? IssueElement {

            let title = currentIssueArticleObject.title ?? ""

            let timeStampDateObject = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: NSTimeInterval(currentIssueArticleObject.timeStamp))
            let timeStampDateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(timeStampDateObject)

            let author = currentIssueArticleObject.author ?? ""

            let issueNumber = currentIssueArticleObject.issueNumber ?? ""
            let volumeNumber = currentIssueArticleObject.volumeNumber ?? ""

            let articleContent = currentIssueArticleObject.articleContent ?? ""

            let nodeID = currentIssueArticleObject.nodeID ?? 0


            cellWithoutCoverImage.currentIssueArticlesHeadlineLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleHeadline)
            cellWithoutCoverImage.currentIssueArticlesHeadlineLabel.text = title

            cellWithoutCoverImage.currentIssueArticlesAuthorLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleSubheadline)
            cellWithoutCoverImage.currentIssueArticlesAuthorLabel.text = author

            cellWithoutCoverImage.currentIssueArticlesPublishDateLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleSubheadline)
            cellWithoutCoverImage.currentIssueArticlesPublishDateLabel.text = timeStampDateString

            return cellWithoutCoverImage;

        } else {
            break
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Because the compiler detects that you are not returning a cell always, what about the last `else` statement, is empty

Comment: Deleted it, still get the same error.

Comment: I posted the revised code.

Comment: Why the F is that function so freaking long. If it's longer than about 5 lines then it shouldn't be one function. Shorter functions are easier to debug and remove all that if else stuff. At least get to a point that makes sense before adding it to StackOverflow.

Comment: Your default still has a an else statement that returns nothing, best way to do this is a have you default return a a UITableVIewCell(), and make sure that code never reached default

Comment: I added a return UITableViewCell() in my last else statement and took out the "break". I'm still getting the error. Why is this stupid ass compiler not seeing that I'm returning the cell ???

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the last `else` in your code cose it's empty. Also you could use a `switch` like:

```
switch(row){
    case 0:{
        // code with the CurrentIssueFrontCoverTableViewCell

        ....
        return cellWithCoverImage;
    }

    default:{

        // code with the CurrentIssueArticlesTableViewCell

        ...
        return cellWithoutCoverImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the error even after switching to a switch-case statement, having also deleted the last else

Answer (score 0):

The comment from Victor is correct. Because if you were to step through every possible outcome of the function, you could possibly reach the end of it without returning anything. You will need to provide a return statement for every possible outcome, including inside all of the 'else' blocks at the end that are currently empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this:

```
} else {
    return
}
```

You can't have empty returns in a method expecting a return type, you need to return something here.

Every code path in your method must end in a return that returns a UITableViewCell. Anything that does not will make the compiler complain.

Comment: that's what I don't get. What kind of object should I be returning ? I don't want it to be anything else than the object I am asking for in my "if" statement...

Comment: Your table view has already asked you how many cells it should present, at this point it's not asking you if there should be a cell (you have already said there should be), but what that cell should be.

Comment: If there is the possibility that some of the items in your array do not fit, you may want to consider having a separate array of only valid objects and using that to control your table view instead. Or alternately, using a swift array that is typed (ex: [IssueElement]) if that's viable. But you MUST return a table view cell here, one way or another.